# Defining TH with Class, is this possible?

Tags: css

I am creating a table and I want 2 types of TH class that uses different background color in a table. Also I might need some help on the DIV tag.

The CSS I'm using is like this:

```html
<div class="one">
 <div class="two">
  <table>
    <TR><TH> one color </TH></TR>
    <TR><TH class="color">differnet color </TH></TR>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

```css
.one .two th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  background: #000000;
}
.one .two th .color {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the space between `th` and `.color`

Otherwise you're looking for a `.color` descendant element inside the `th`, not for the class on the `th` itself.

Comment: My love for computers goes beyond what I can express.  One space that has killed 2.5 hour of my life.  Thank you computers!

But yes that did the trick!

A follow up question, if I had not defined [.one .two th.color] instead just used [th.color] will it still have worked?

Comment: Yes, but if you have any other `<th class="color">` on the page than they would be affected too.

Answer (score 0):

If you generally want to color every nth or odd/even row, you can use the :nth-child() selector without specifying a class on each such row.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #000;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #fff;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child